# Creating new named variable in dataframe using loop and naming convention

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

One of the most frustrating things about R is the difficulty of creating new dataframe variables using names, algorithmically and intuitively.

Suppose I have a dataframe with some variables, and want to create new variables based on them in a loop. For example, I want to create new variables which are the cumulative sum of existing variables, and named `df$var_cumul`

```
temp<-as.data.frame(cbind(seq(0:10),seq(10:20)))
names(temp)<-c("x","y")
for (i in 1:ncol(temp)) {
  vname<-names(temp)[i]
  assign(paste("temp$",vname,"_cumul",sep=""),cumsum(contrs[,i]))
}
```

No permuation of that I've found works.  This is probably one of my biggest issue with R on a regular basis.

Is there an easy intuitive way to do this?

Comment: You need to study the help page for "[[" more carefully. The key is avoidance of the futile effort to make `$<-` do something it cannot do. It would also help if you unlearned the abomination of `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`

Comment: .. also never ever use `1:ncol`, `1:nrow` or `1:length` ... (it doesn't do what you think it does and such cases are a pain to debug ...) - you want to use `seq_len()` and friends instead.

Comment: With DWin's second point, I believe he's referring to the fact that `data.frame(x = 1:11, y = 1:11)` is (among other things) a whole lot less typing. I would seriously recommend playing around with the output of things like `seq(10:20)` because that's pretty horrible too. (Reading `?seq` would be a good start.)

Comment: My point was that `cbind` coerces to a matrix, which removes all attributes and makes all columns the "lowest possible denominator" generally a character matrix.

Comment: DWin - I'd say that I'd need to *find* the "[[' page first! It didn't come up in any search or reference about achieving this, and I'm sorry to say I'm not going to read every reference manual page. Hopefully I'll be able to reference this from now on.   Much thanks!

Comment: Type: ..........  `?"[["`    One _should_ read the manual pages for the functions one uses. You could have typed `?"$<-"` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the `[[` operator:

```
temp <- data.frame(x = 0:10, y = 10:20)

for (n in names(temp))
  temp[[paste0(n, "_cumsum")]] <- cumsum(temp[[n]])
```

Comment: If I want to create 3 dataframe can I create it in a for loop? my case is 
for(i in 1:3){
 df.i <- data.frame(something)
}